# shuffle a deck of cards and cut it into three piles ,what probability that (at least) a court card will turn up on top of one of the piles?

Tags: probability

shuffle a deck of cards and cut it into three piles ,what probability that (at least) a court card will turn up on top of one of the piles ?
Hint : there are 12 court card ( four jacks,four queens and four kings ) in the deck

Comment: The pile stuff is irrelevant, if the piles must be non-empty, it is the same as if we are drawing $3$ cards. If empty piles are allowed, the problem is more interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  you are drawing three cards from the deck without replacement.  What is the probability that the first one is not a court card?  Given that the first was a non-court card, what is the chance the second is not a court card?  So the chance that neither the first nor the second is a court card is what?  One more step for the third.